# I can be your happiness or your misery. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> Everyone is part of me,
>      even before the moment they open their eyes,
>      doesn't matter if they are alive or not.
>   I can be your happiness or your misery.
>   You can leave me, but I will never leave you.
>   Time can change me, but I can also change the time.
>   I am the most powerful drug.
>   Some spend their entire lives trying to find me.
>   I can never be consumed, I can never be destroyed.
>   I am everything and nothing,

**Who am I?**

Comment: I like your riddles, but they would be even better when you add a title that is more descriptive of the riddle, for example, a line from the riddle.

Comment: You may want to give some feedback on the answers attempted thus far, and/or offer a hint as forward progress seems to have stopped.

Answer (score 4):

I guess at this point, it can gather many answers. Here's a try..

Are you -

> **An illusion or a dream**

Everyone is part of me, even before the moment they open their eyes, doesn't matter if they are alive or not.

> Illusion/Dream of an unborn baby is possible. Also illusion/dream of ghosts are possible.

I can be your happiness or your misery.

> Illusion/Dream of something good gives happiness while illusion of something bad gives misery.

You can leave me, but I will never leave you.

> We may avoid illusions but they are still there in our mind. Similarly, we can wake up and end the dream.

Time can change me, but I can also change the time.
I am the most powerful drug.

> Illusions may change with time and an illusion may change time. Powerful illusions act as if you are drugged. Similarly, dreams may change with time. And dreaming can be like drugging.

Some spend their entire lives trying to find me.

> Illusions have been widely studied. Similarly, people keep following their dreams.

I can never be consumed, I can never be destroyed.
I am everything and nothing,

> Illusions can show everything that you wish to see. But nothing is true. Same goes for the dreams.

Comment: You have reached the door, but you forgot the key, maybe this will give you a hint.

Answer (score 1):

You may be:

> **The past**, or perhaps, History or Memory

Everyone is part of me, even before the moment they open their eyes, doesn't matter if they are alive or not.

> From the moment someone is conceived, they become part of the present, and as each moment then passes, they accompany it into the past.

I can be your happiness or your misery.

> Our past can be happy, or miserable.

You can leave me, but I will never leave you.

> We always remain in the present, not the past, but we can never leave our past behind.

Time can change me, but I can also change the time.

> As time goes by, it is added to the past.  Also, sometimes the past is rewritten (not literally, but our understanding or our remembrance of it) as the greater perspective of time changes our view or knowledge of the past.  And as the present slips into the past, the current time changes.

I am the most powerful drug.
Some spend their entire lives trying to find me.

> What we leave behind us (our past) is also our legacy - people may spend their whole lives looking for something meaningful to leave behind.  The appeal of leaving a positive mark on the world is as powerful as any drug.

I can never be consumed, I can never be destroyed.

> The past cannot be consumed or destroyed.

I am everything and nothing.

> Everything that has ever been is now in the past. And yet it is not a thing that can be seen or felt, so *no thing* indeed.

Comment: You must look for The Holy Mountain, perhaps there you will find what is left.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for

> Love

- Everyone is part of me, even before the moment they open their eyes.

> We are most of the time born by the process of love. So we are made of love even before we are born. It can also refers to the parents love for the children.

- Doesn't matter if they are alive or not.

> You can still love the dead people you have loved when they were still there.

- I can be your happiness or your misery.

> Love can bring wonderful moments of happiness. But when things are going bad, for exemple in a relationship, it can hurts a lot, and sometimes drive us to some misery states.

- Time can change me, but I can also change the time.

> With the time, the love you have for someone can be modified, in good or bad ways. But it can also makes the time you live with someone go way faster (or way slower) depending on the situation.

- I am the most powerful drug.

> I don't think any explanation is needed there.

- Some spend their entire lives trying to find me.

> People often seek for the person they will love for their entire life, and that will love them the same way. It can also simply refer to the idea of finding people around you who will take care of us and love us.

- I am everything and nothing.

> For us love is everything. We are born from love, nearly everything which is around us is/has been made by people who were born from love too. Most of us are making of love one of their inner life goal. The same way, without love, everything would be nothing.

Comment: You have the key, but you don't have the door, but without the door, how can you know this is the key?, perhaps you should use this hint.

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer

Are you

> Carbon

Everyone is part of me, even before the moment they open their eyes, doesn't matter if they are alive or not.

> Carbon is part of every dead or alive

I can be your happiness or your misery.

> Carbons in form of diamond can give happiness and misery

You can leave me, but I will never leave you.

> We leave carbon in form of excreta but still our body has carbon

Time can change me, but I can also change the time.

> Over the period of time  carbon changes it form like petroleum products or diamonds but if someone finds some good diamonds your time will change(make you wealthy)

I am the most powerful drug.

> Again any useful form (like diamond or currency notes) wealth can be powerful drug to avoid

Some spend their entire lives trying to find me.

> People keep looking for petroleum at various places like ocean or deep down inside earth

I can never be consumed, I can never be destroyed.
I am everything and nothing,

> These I am not very sure about

**EDIT**

Another answer I can think that fits almost all the criteria is

> Space

Comment: You showed a unique line of thought, and i thank you for that, perhaps if let yourself drown in the concept of your answer, you can find a key, to show you something you must see.

Comment: @Iry-Hor I added another possible answer which can fit here.

Answer (score 0):

> Truth

Everyone is part of me, even before the moment they open their eyes, doesn't matter if they are alive or not.

> Everyone is the part of the truth i.e the universe, humans, etc.

I can be your happiness or your misery.

> Truth for some could bring happiness and for some it could be bitter.

You can leave me, but I will never leave you.

> You can avoid the truth but it stays put.

Time can change me, but I can also change the time.

> Possibly, refers to how truth can change i.e say, pluto is a planet but later its not :P.

I am the most powerful drug.

> 

Some spend their entire lives trying to find me.

> Saints leaving everything to go in search of truth.

I can never be consumed, I can never be destroyed.

> Truth remains as it is. It stays. It cannot be destroyed as it can only be avoided.

I am everything and nothing,

> 

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> attraction (gravity)

Everyone is part of me, even before the moment they open their eyes, doesn't matter if they are alive or not.

> Everyone is causing his own gravitational field no matter their sate

I can be your happiness or your misery.

> Jumping in a pool will cause happiness, landing on hard ground causes misery

You can leave me, but I will never leave you.

> I can leave the gravitational field of another object but my own will always stay with me

Time can change me, but I can also change the time.

> See gravitational waves and black holes

I am the most powerful drug.

> Cliffjumping, Rollercoaster, etc

Some spend their entire lives trying to find me.

> either gravitational phenomenons or so/sth attractive

I can never be consumed, I can never be destroyed.

> You cannot consume or destroy the gravitational field of matter

I am everything and nothing,

> Gravity is everywhere and plays an important role in our universe but is nothing compared to other forces

Answer (score 0):

My Answer:

> Memory

Everyone is part of me, even before the moment they open their eyes, doesn't matter if they are alive or not.

> Everyone is part of the collective memory of society

I can be your happiness or your misery.

> Remembering can be a joy or sadness

You can leave me, but I will never leave you.

> People may forget you... memories can haunt/follow you

Time can change me, but I can also change the time.

> Time changes our sense of memory... What we remember changes our perception of time passing

I am the most powerful drug.

> Memory can console, depress, etc...

Some spend their entire lives trying to find me.

> Amnesiacs

I can never be consumed, I can never be destroyed.

> You can't consume or destroy memory in general.

I am everything and nothing,

> How you remember something is everything... but a memory really is nothing

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possible answers, but they are probably both wrong....

... and if one is correct you will probably have to explain a bit more for me to understand...

1. Are you

> Energy?

Everyone is part of me, even before the moment they open their eyes, doesn't 
matter if they are alive or not.

> We all have some potential energy, kinetic energy etc.

I can be your happiness or your misery.

> lack of energy could be misery

You can leave me, but I will never leave you.

> not sure - this may not fit

Time can change me, but I can also change the time.

> energy can change from one form to another - and in different gravitational potentials the speed of time can change or from acceleration to high speed (e.g. twins paradox - due to relativity)

I am the most powerful drug.

> exercising can be a powerful drug....

Some spend their entire lives trying to find me.

> people try to get fit

I can never be consumed, I can never be destroyed.

> energy can neither be created nor destroyed

I am everything and nothing,

> energy is in everything, but not a particular thing on its own

So that was first attempt....

... now second attempt

2. Are you

> God or some spiritual being/lifeforce idea

Everyone is part of me, even before the moment they open their eyes, doesn't 
matter if they are alive or not.

> this could be argued spiritually

I can be your happiness or your misery.

> this fits as well

You can leave me, but I will never leave you.

> this fits as well

Time can change me, but I can also change the time.

> first part may not fit, but second part fits

I am the most powerful drug.

> spiritual experiences can be very powerful...

Some spend their entire lives trying to find me.

> this fits

I can never be consumed, I can never be destroyed.

> and this fits

I am everything and nothing,

> not sure about this part

so to conclude.....

> one scientific answer and one more 'spiritual' answer....